Monstache sync error: which is larger than the limit of [751619276/716.7mb] [type=circuit_breaking_exception]
I'm currently using Monstache to sync data from MongoDB to Elasticsearch, and I'm encountering circuit breaker exceptions during the process.
Here are the specifics of my setup:

Cluster Configuration: 2GB/30GB cluster
Initial Sync Size: 5 million records
Real-Time Sync Load: 200 requests per minute
Search Query Load: 200 requests per minute

Below is my monstache toml file


# connection settings

# connect to MongoDB using the following URL
#mongo-url = "<MONGO_URL>"
mongo-url = "<MONGO_URL>/?readConcernLevel=majority&readPreference=secondary"

# connect to the Elasticsearch REST API at the following node URLs
elasticsearch-urls = ["<ELASTIC_SEARCH_URLS>"] # Array of connection string

# frequently required settings

# if you need to seed an index from a collection and not just listen and sync changes events
# you can copy entire collections or views from MongoDB to Elasticsearch
direct-read-namespaces = ["live.chassistypes", "live.chassisowners", "live.containertypes", "live.containerowners", "live.equipment", "live.drivers", "live.customers", "live.loads"]
change-stream-namespaces = ["live.chassistypes", "live.chassisowners", "live.containertypes", "live.containerowners", "live.equipment", "live.drivers", "live.customers", "live.loads"]


elasticsearch-api-key = "<ELASTIC_SEARCH_API_KEY>"

resume = true

resume-write-unsafe = false

resume-name = "sync-latest"

resume-strategy = 1

verbose=true

direct-read-split-max = 1000  # Limit the number of documents processed per split
direct-read-concur = 2       # Reduce concurrency for direct reads


# Server failure handle and auto restart, searcher helth checkup configuration
elasticsearch-retry = true           # Enable automatic retry on failures
elasticsearch-max-seconds = 60      # Maximum time Monstache should wait for a response from Elasticsearch
elasticsearch-max-conns = 10         # Maximum number of concurrent connections to Elasticsearch
elasticsearch-healthcheck-timeout = 5  # Interval to check if Elasticsearch is healthy

# Script middleware for syncing
[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.chassistypes"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/chassisTypeSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.chassisowners"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/chassisOwnerSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.containertypes"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/containerTypesSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.containerowners"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/containerOwnersSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.equipment"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/equipmentSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.drivers"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/driversSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.customers"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/customersSync.js"

[[pipeline]]
namespace = "live.loads"
path = "./src/elasticSyncScripts/loadSync.js"

# Mapping mongo read namespace and elastic store index 
[[mapping]]
namespace="live.chassistypes"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.chassisowners"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.containertypes"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.containerowners"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.equipment"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.drivers"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.customers"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[[mapping]]
namespace="live.loads"
index="live-mastersearch-index"

[logs]
error="./src/monstacheSyncLogs/error.txt"
warn="./src/monstacheSyncLogs/warn.txt"
# info="./src/monstacheSyncLogs/info.txt"
# trace="./src/monstacheSyncLogs/trace.txt"
# stats="./src/monstacheSyncLogs/stats.txt"

And i am getting this error while realtime syncing
ERROR 2024/12/20 10:34:51 elastic: bulk processor "monstache" failed but may retry: elastic: Error 429 (Too Many Requests): [parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [954104862/909.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [858993459/819.1mb], real usage: [937326936/893.9mb], new bytes reserved: [16777926/16mb], usages [model_inference=0/0b, eql_sequence=0/0b, fielddata=5586/5.4kb, request=0/0b, inflight_requests=38822354/37mb] [type=circuit_breaking_exception]
ERROR 2024/12/20 10:35:00 elastic: bulk processor "monstache" failed but may retry: elastic: Error 429 (Too Many Requests): rejected execution of coordinating operation [coordinating_and_primary_bytes=74496147, replica_bytes=25403291, all_bytes=99899438, coordinating_operation_bytes=10284532, max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=107374182] [type=es_rejected_execution_exception]


Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

how many nodes? looks like spreading the load between more nodes would fix this

i have created 3 shards of my index
"settings": {
"number_of_shards": 3, // Number of primary shards for distribution
"number_of_replicas": 1
},
are you talking about this shards?.

@A.Stern is there any other way to sync realtime in elastic, can u tell me my server size good for handle that much load or requests??

I do not mean shards count.
OpenSearch/Elasticsearch can be run as a cluster where you have multiple nodes help distribute load of classic Lucene indexing and searching between multiple machines.
In this case you are getting "Error 429 (Too Many Requests)" which means you might be overloading the single instance you are using to run Elasticsearch. The single node cluster mode is not the best use of this technology, and contradicts its raison d'etre.

If you are using Elasticsearch as a service ("Elastic cloud" i belive) then perhaps raise the issue with their support.
